# Assinar NFs-e em C# gera erro Elemento Reference mal formado

Tags: c#, xml, assinatura-digital

do nada o meu código em C# parou de assinar as NFs-e de Curitiba. Na linha do código abaixo, dá o erro:

```
signedXml.ComputeSignature();
```

#### Errro

```
Elemento Reference mal formado
```

Alguém sabe se pode ser algo a ver com o certificado? Pois sempre funcionou e parou do nada, sem atualizar o sistema.

#### Assinatura

```
private void Assinar(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 certificado, string tag)
{
    XmlNodeList listaTagsAssinar = doc.GetElementsByTagName(tag);
    SignedXml signedXml;

    foreach (XmlElement infNFe in listaTagsAssinar)
    {

        // obter o valor da propriedade "Id" da tag que será assinada

        string id = "";
        if (infNFe.HasAttribute("id"))
            id = infNFe.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;
        else if (infNFe.HasAttribute("Id"))
            id = infNFe.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Id").Value;
        else if (infNFe.HasAttribute("ID"))
            id = infNFe.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID").Value;
        else if (infNFe.HasAttribute("iD"))
            id = infNFe.Attributes.GetNamedItem("iD").Value;
        else
            throw new Exception("Tag " + tag + " não tem atributo Id");


        signedXml = new SignedXml(infNFe);
        signedXml.SigningKey = certificado.PrivateKey;

        // Transformações p/ DigestValue da Nota
        Reference reference = new Reference("#" + id);
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod += "#WithComments";

        //reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado));
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // gerar o valor da assinatura
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // criar elemento <Signature>
        XmlElement xmlSignature = doc.CreateElement("Signature", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

        // criar Id da tag <Signature>
        XmlAttribute idAssinatura = doc.CreateAttribute("Id");
        idAssinatura.Value = "Ass_" + id.Replace(":", "_");
        xmlSignature.Attributes.InsertAfter(idAssinatura, xmlSignature.GetAttributeNode("xmlns"));

        // gerar elemento <SignedInfo>
        XmlElement xmlSignedInfo = signedXml.SignedInfo.GetXml();

        // gerar elemento <KeyInfo>
        XmlElement xmlKeyInfo = signedXml.KeyInfo.GetXml();

        // compor nó <SignatureValue>
        XmlElement xmlSignatureValue = doc.CreateElement("SignatureValue", xmlSignature.NamespaceURI);
        string signBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.Signature.SignatureValue);
        XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode(signBase64);
        xmlSignatureValue.AppendChild(text);

        // incluir nós filhos da assinatura
        xmlSignature.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlSignedInfo, true));
        xmlSignature.AppendChild(xmlSignatureValue);
        xmlSignature.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlKeyInfo, true));

        // incluir assinatura no documento
        infNFe.ParentNode.AppendChild(xmlSignature);
    }
}
```

### Dados da Chamada

#### XmlDoc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LoteRps Id="123456" xmlns="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/">
    <NumeroLote>620</NumeroLote>
    <Cnpj>01188703000158</Cnpj>
    <InscricaoMunicipal>000000003311870</InscricaoMunicipal>
    <QuantidadeRps>1</QuantidadeRps>
    <ListaRps>
      <Rps>
        <InfRps>
          <IdentificacaoRps>
            <Numero>620</Numero>
            <Serie>RPS</Serie>
            <Tipo>1</Tipo>
          </IdentificacaoRps>
          <DataEmissao>2016-03-09T09:00:48.923</DataEmissao>
          <NaturezaOperacao>1</NaturezaOperacao>
          <RegimeEspecialTributacao>1</RegimeEspecialTributacao>
          <OptanteSimplesNacional>2</OptanteSimplesNacional>
          <IncentivadorCultural>2</IncentivadorCultural>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Servico>
            <Valores>
              <ValorServicos>862.81</ValorServicos>
              <ValorDeducoes>0.00</ValorDeducoes>
              <ValorPis>5.61</ValorPis>
              <ValorCofins>25.88</ValorCofins>
              <ValorInss>0.00</ValorInss>
              <ValorIr>12.94</ValorIr>
              <ValorCsll>8.63</ValorCsll>
              <IssRetido>2</IssRetido>
              <ValorIss>43.14</ValorIss>
              <ValorIssRetido>0.00</ValorIssRetido>
              <OutrasRetencoes>0.00</OutrasRetencoes>
              <BaseCalculo>862.81</BaseCalculo>
              <Aliquota>0.05</Aliquota>
              <ValorLiquidoNfse>809.75</ValorLiquidoNfse>
              <DescontoIncondicionado>0.00</DescontoIncondicionado>
              <DescontoCondicionado>0.00</DescontoCondicionado>
            </Valores>
            <ItemListaServico>0408</ItemListaServico>
            <CodigoCnae>0</CodigoCnae>
            <Discriminacao>CONSULTA MÉDICA     Qtde.: 9     Vlr. Unit. R$ 30,00     Vlr. Total R$ 270,00\r\nREF.02/2016-Euro Import.\r\nCONSULTA MÉDICA     Qtde.: 4     Vlr. Unit. R$ 30,00     Vlr. Total R$ 120,00\r\nREF.02/2016.-SUL IMPORT\r\nCONSULTA MÉDICA     Qtde.: 15     Vlr. Unit. R$ 30,00     Vlr. Total R$ 450,00\r\nRef.Fevereiro/2016 - AR SUDESTE\r\nAUDIOMETRIA     Qtde.: 1     Vlr. Unit. R$ 15,00     Vlr. Total R$ 15,00\r\nRef.Fevereiro/2016 - Sul Import\r\nEXS. LABORATÓRIO     Qtde.: 1     Vlr. Unit. R$ 7,81     Vlr. Total R$ 7,81\r\nRef.FEVEREIRO/2016 -Sul Import\r\n\r\nPara pagamento, fazer depósito:\r\nAUDIOMED - Banco Itaú Ag 3702 C/C 04568-7\r\nVencimento da NF: 30/03/2016\r\nConforme Lei Federal 12.741, informamos o percentual de impostos incidentes sobre esta nota fiscal: 16,33%</Discriminacao>
            <CodigoMunicipio>4106902</CodigoMunicipio>
          </Servico>
          <Prestador>
            <Cnpj>01188703000158</Cnpj>
            <InscricaoMunicipal>000000003311870</InscricaoMunicipal>
          </Prestador>
          <Tomador>
            <IdentificacaoTomador>
              <CpfCnpj>
                <Cnpj>07318719000114</Cnpj>
              </CpfCnpj>
            </IdentificacaoTomador>
            <RazaoSocial>AVANTI ENGENHARIA DE SEGURANÇA E SAUDE OCUPACIONAL</RazaoSocial>
            <Endereco>
              <Endereco>R: Parque Domingos Luis</Endereco>
              <Numero>141</Numero>
              <Bairro>Jardim São Paulo</Bairro>
              <CodigoMunicipio>3550308</CodigoMunicipio>
              <Uf>SP</Uf>
              <Cep>2043081</Cep>
            </Endereco>
            <Contato>
              <Telefone>1122832308</Telefone>
              <Email>ocupacional@avantiengenharia.com.br; administracao@avantiengenharia.com.br</Email>
            </Contato>
          </Tomador>
        </InfRps>
      </Rps>
    </ListaRps>
  </LoteRps>
</EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
```

#### Tag

LoteRps

Comment: @Bacco adicionado mais dados

Comment: Já melhorou um bocado. Vamos ver se o pessoal que tem prática em C# consegue ajudar. Aí, se precisarem de mais detalhes, eles podem comentar aqui também.

Comment: No meu caso, estou com Windows 10. No início do mês funcionou mas de lá para cá tivemos updates e eu acho que alguma coisa dentro do .NET mudou. Continuo com as buscas....

Comment: Não consigo responder, provavelmente porque minha reputação é global (stackexchange) e não local. Segui isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099156/malformed-reference-element-when-adding-a-reference-based-on-an-id-attribute-w e funcionou. Mudei para `nsManager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd");` e `doc.SelectSingleNode("//x:EnviarLoteRpsEnvio//x:LoteRps//x:ListaRps//x:Rps//x:InfRps[@Id=\"" + id + "\"]", nsManager)`

Comment: Olá Creio que Seja pelo ID começar com números. O correto é iniciar o ID com letras. Veja possível tópico duplicado abaixo:
[Assinatura Digital](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118481/assinatura-digital-de-lote-de-rps-nfs-e-erro-elemento-de-refer%C3%AAncia-mal-forma)

Comment: a minha pergunta não está duplicada, ela foi perguntada antes desta que você falou. Veja que perguntei em 10/03 e do seu link em 16/03.