# Assinatura Digital de Lote de RPS (NFS-e) erro: Elemento de referência mal formado

Tags: .net

Temos um sistema que envia lotes de RPS para prefeituras de várias cidades do Brasil. O sistema estava enviando os lotes de RPS sem problemas, mas na sexta-feira passada (11/03/2016) parou de funcionar e apresentou a mensagem: **Elemento de referência mal formado**. Identificamos que este erro ocorre no momento da assinatura do arquivo XML (**signedXml.ComputeSignature()**).

Para resolver este problema, desinstalamos todas as **atualizações do Windows** do dia anterior (10/03/2016) referente a: Atualização de Segurança para Microsoft Windows - KB3140735, KB3140410; KB3139940; KB3139929; KB3139914; KB3139852; KB3139398; KB3138962; KB3138910; KB3135988; KB3135983 e Atualização para Microsoft Windows - KB3138612; KB3121255; KB3118401; KB2952664. (Nota: Não identificamos qual dessas atualizações gerou este problema)

[image: Atualizações do Windows desinstaladas]

Espero que esta dica ajude quem estiver com este problema.

Configurações que estou usando:
SO: Windows 7 32 bits
Plataforma de Desenvolvimento: VB.Net - Visual Studio 2010 (Framework 3.5)

Se alguém souber resolver este problema, sem precisar desinstalar as atualizações do windows, eu agradeço.

Abraço.
Alexandre Melo

Comment: No caso do Windows 10, "resolvi" o problemas removendo a atualização: KB-3140768.Mas isso não é uma solução! Assim como o Alexandre, também gostaria uma solução. Não consegui implementar a solução descrita neste tópico: [Possível solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117568/assinar-nfs-e-em-c-gera-erro-elemento-reference-mal-formado) Abraço

Comment: no windows server 2008 instale o certificado da MS que resolve, no 2012 ainda estou testando uma solução prática. Certificado:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=747875&clcid=0x409 Flayner

Answer (score 3):

Problema corrigido.

Após atualização do framework, foi feita uma correção de vulnerabilidade nas assinaturas.

Junto com essa correção, algumas regras para formar o Id de um XML que será assinado.

1o. O `Id` precisa começar com letras, não pode iniciar com numeros;
2o. O caracter `/` não é mais aceito no conteúdo do `Id`. Imagino que outros   caracteres especiais tambem não sejam aceitos, como `:;^~,` etc

Comment: Você é o mesmo que criou a pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

O suporte da Microsoft que trata desse tema está no seguinte endereço:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3148821

Mesmo após instalar a nova chave no registro da máquina, a solução só apareceu com a desinstalação do KB3140745, no meu caso.

Na documentacao da MS, tem as atualizações para cada versao de sistema e framework