# Elemento de referência mal formado: Assinatura Digital

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Acabei tendo o mesmo problema sobre um post já feito aqui, porém vêm uma dúvida junto ao que foi postado no artigo. Qual atualização do windows seria para remover dentre as citadas neste [artigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118481/assinatura-digital-de-lote-de-rps-nfs-e-erro-elemento-de-refer%C3%AAncia-mal-forma)? (a remoção seria um paliativo até resolver o problema)

Fora a dúvida sobre o artigo, segue o código que estou com problemas.

```
public void AssinarElementos(XmlDocument Document, X509Certificate2 x509, string ParentElementName, string ElementName, string AttributeName)
    {

        XmlElement elInf;
        string elInfID;
        SignedXml elSigned;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider Key;
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        // Retira chave privada ligada ao certificado
        Key = ((RSACryptoServiceProvider)(x509.PrivateKey));
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(x509));
        foreach (XmlElement ele in Document.GetElementsByTagName(ParentElementName))
        {
            elInf = ((XmlElement)(ele.GetElementsByTagName(ElementName)[(ele.GetElementsByTagName(ElementName).Count - 1)]));
            elInfID = elInf.Attributes.GetNamedItem(AttributeName).Value;
            elSigned = new SignedXml(elInf);

            // Seta chaves
            elSigned.SigningKey = Key;
            elSigned.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            //  Cria referencia
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = ("#" + elInfID);
            //  Adiciona tranformacao a referencia
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform(false));
            //  Adiciona referencia ao xml
            elSigned.AddReference(reference);
            //  Calcula Assinatura
            elSigned.ComputeSignature();
            // Adiciona assinatura
            ele.AppendChild(Document.ImportNode(elSigned.GetXml(), true));
        }
    }
```

É gerado um erro de `Elemento de referência mal formado.`, na linha onde vai executar o `elSigned.ComputeSignature();` (Fiz um teste em uma máquina com windows 10 e funcionou perfeitamente).

Uma das respostas no [artigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118481/assinatura-digital-de-lote-de-rps-nfs-e-erro-elemento-de-refer%C3%AAncia-mal-forma) comentavam sobre o caracter `/` que estaria sendo inválido e provavelmente outros caracteres como `:;^~,` seriam considerados inválidos. Eu como utilizo o caracter `#` ao id seria um problema?

Comment: O ID agora precisa começar com letra, não podendo mais ser iniciado com números e também não pode mais conter caracteres especiais...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A atualização do windows 7 para ser removida (solução paliativa), é a `KB3135983`.

No caso é ela que faz essa nova "requisição" de segurança no xml agora.

Está confirmado que o ID necessita começar com letra apenas, não podendo conter caracteres especiais em seu ID.

Caso utilize a solução paliativa é recomendado apenas ocultar também a atualização para evitar possíveis retornos dela na máquina. Segue a imagem no windows update possibilitando desabilitar a atualização específica (mesmo em modo automático).

**Obs: Vale ressaltar que a remoção da atualização é apenas para que o sistema continue em seu funcionamento até que se atualize removendo o problema posterior, obtendo o menor impacto ao usuário final (direta ou indiretamente).**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]